# MySQL Load XML Using Both Tag names and attribute values as columns

Tags: mysql, xml-parsing

I'm having a problem loading XML into a database table using LOAD XML INFILE. An example of my XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ProductList>
  <Product>
    <SKU>ABC123</SKU>
    <Description>The product name</Description>
    <Images>
      <Name>ABC123.JPG</Name>
      <ImagePath Type="Large">path/to/large/ABC123.JPG</ImagePath>
      <ImagePath Type="Small">path/to/small/ABC123.JPG</ImagePath>
    </Images>
  </Product>
</ProductList>
```

I have a database table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `images` (
  `SKU` varchar(25) NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NULL,
  `Large` varchar(100) NULL,
  `Small` varchar(100) NULL,
  KEY `Sku` (`SKU`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And I'm using the following query to load:

```
LOAD XML INFILE '/path/to/xml'
INTO TABLE `images`
ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Images>';
```

It's loading the Name value into the table but the Large and Small fields are not getting populated. In reading through the MySQL docs it looks like it can support reading attributes as column headings but it doesn't specify if it can do a mix of using both tag names and attribute values as column names in the same row set.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html

Can anyone help? Is it possible to read in the image information from the XML layout I have into a single table with one row per  record, populating all three fields of name, large, and small?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML doesn't match any of the three XML formats that can be read by LOAD XML INFILE.

You're going to have to write a script to parse your XML input, read the nested tags to find the paths for the three different images you want, and then construct a custom INSERT statement to execute.